# Symfony2 URL matcher throwing ResourceNotFoundError when matching controller during translate function

Tags: php, symfony, locale, translate

I've got an error that is only happening on production. I have a form that uses radio buttons to change the language translation of my application. When the user selects "en", the application changes to English, etc.

On production, toggling the radio button throws an error:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception (ResourceNotFoundException) ... at ... app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:129
```

That line just throws the ResourceNotFoundException, but the line I'm looking at:

```
if (preg_match('#^/(?P<_locale>[^/]++)/translate$#s', $pathinfo, $matches)) {
    return $this->mergeDefaults(array_replace($matches, array('_route' => 'translate_language')), array ( '_controller' => 'Path\\ToMy\\Controller\\TranslateController::translateAction',));
}
```

The code works inside the preg_match but fails on the return. All my other routes work!

Below is my translateAction code:

```
public function translateAction(Request $request)
{
 $form = $this->createTranslateForm();
 $form->handleRequest($request);

 if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $data = $request->request->get('translate-form');
    $language = $data['language'];

    $this->get('session')->set('_locale', $language);

    $referRoute = $this->getRefererRoute();

    $url = $this->get('router')->generate($referRoute, array('_locale' => $language));

    return $this->redirect($url);
 }
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on what's going on here?

Comment: The exception said that symfony can't find the route, it means there's some typo in the path to the action. The prod is case-sensitive.

Comment: I don't see how/where this is possible. The preg_match works, a die() works inside that preg_match. This would indicate the issue is around the mergeDefaults ?!

Comment: It said symfony can't find this action 'Path\\ToMy\\Controller\\TranslateController::translateAction'